# batch file(.bat) showing unexpected behaviour

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line

My batch Script:-

```
@echo off

:alpha

rasdial "connection_name" connection_id connection_pass> tmpFile 
set /p myvar= < tmpFile 
del tmpFile 
echo %myvar%
if "%myvar%" == "You are already connected to Broadband Connection." (exit)
goto alpha
```

This script is expected to run a command `radial ...` and then store the output of the command in a temprory file `tempFile`. Then it assigns the stored output of command `radial` inside this file to a variable, and deletes the file. The variable in turn is used to check whether the command got successfully executed or not (if command executed successfully then `You are already connected to Broadband Connection.` will be the output).

But upon executing this batch file I get output:-

```
Connecting to Broadband Connection...
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

and then the script breaks. Instead of looping through it again, until the command get's successfully executed.

**OUTPUT AFTER ECHO ON:-**

```
rasdial "Broadband Connection" uname pass  1>tmpFile

set /p myvar=   0<tmpFile

del tmpFile

echo You are already connected to Broadband Connection.
You are already connected to Broadband Connection.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

if "You are already connected to Broadband Connection.
Command completed successfully." == "You are already connected to Broadband Connection." (exit)
```

Comment: change `echo off` to `echo on`, run again and show us the output. Change letters and numbers to `X` for username and password, *but leave other chars unchanged*, they may make a difference.

Comment: Does the rasdial command work outside the script ?

Comment: @Marged yes it does

Comment: @Stephan Tried as you stated, but didn't worked

Comment: `echo on` isn't a magically "make-it-work-command", it's a troubleshooting step. Copy-paste the output into your question - else we are not able to read it.

Comment: @Stephan done as you said

Comment: Besides that: I would suggest to use `find` or `findstr` to scan that file for a specific string

Comment: The variable `myvar` seems to contain a line feed (yes, that's unexpected), ruining your `if` syntax.

Comment: @Stephan if the command is ran standalone by itself, then if the command gets successfully executed and if we try to run the command again  then the output is `You are already connected to Broadband Connection.
Command completed successfully.` and these two lines come out at different lines.

Comment: yes, but that's no proper line feed. `<tmpfile set /p myvar=` is supposed to take exactly one line (the first one) from the file, but here it takes two lines - that means, the line feed isn't `CRLF` as expected, but `LF` only. The screen takes that as a line break, but `set /p` doesn't. See my answer (based on @Marged's suggestion) for another method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `myvar` seems to contain a line feed (yes, that's really unexpected), ruining your if syntax.

You should switch to another method (suggested by @Marged)

```
:alpha
rasdial "Broadband Connection" uname pass  | find "You are already connected to Broadband Connection." && exit /b
timeout 1 >nul
goto :alpha
```

This pipes the ouptut of `rasdial` directly to the `find` command. `&&` works as "If `find` is successful" (the string is found), then execute the `exit` command.

Tip: never build an infinite loop without some idle time (did it with `timeout` here) to prevent the CPU from running at 100%.